# Multidimensional arrays in Pandas columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, multidimensional-array, pytables

I have data that will consist of a number of attributes which may be described by arrays of arbitrary length (eg., an object can contain some number of clusters and I want to store the sizes of each constituent cluster as a column, but the number of clusters per object can range from 0 to \infty, in principle). Is there a way to support arrays of any length as column data in a Pandas dataframe? I realize I could use a panel, but AFAIK one would need to know the depth of the panel (which in principle I can't know until I've loaded the data) and in addition the panel may be very sparse since in the example, many objects may have only very few clusters.

If I just use a numpy array with dtype=object, will there be any implications for storing in H5Store or in the performance of Pandas selections or anything else?

Comment: Couldn't you add a column called 'cluster_id' and store it all in a simple dataframe?

Comment: Ah, you mean a column can contain dataframes? Does this have any performance implications? I read somewhere that using a numpy.array as column data will not allow for certain Pandas optimizations, but if this is not the case for dataframes as column data, then great!

Comment: If you have a dataframe for each cluster with columns ['A', 'B', 'C'] combine them into a new dataframe with columns ['ID', 'A', 'B', 'C'] where ID is a unique identifier per cluster. So you would have 'one' huge dataframe (no columns contain dataframes) where each cluster would have more than one row. I can post a more detailed explanation as answer if needed

Comment: Yes, an example would be great.

Here is a schematic of the scenario I am trying to use Pandas for:
  
* object 1: [cluster 1a, cluster 1b, cluster 1c]  
* object 2: [cluster 2a, cluster 2b, ... cluster 2z]  
* object 3: [cluster 3a]  
* ...  
* object n: [cluster na, ... cluster nk]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of varying number of columns per object you would have varying number of rows per object

```
pd.DataFrame({'ClusterID' : '1a,1b,2a,2b,2c,2d,3a'.split(','), 'ObjectID' : [1,1,2,2,2,2,3]})
  ObjectID  ClusterID
0        1         1a
1        1         1b
2        2         2a
3        2         2b
4        2         2c
5        2         2d
6        3         3a
```

If each cluster has multiple attributes, you could store them in a separate table as below. This would allow multiple objects to share clusters without having to replicate data

```
pd.DataFrame({'ClusterID' : '1a,1b,2a,2b,2c,2d,3a'.split(','), 'ClusterAttr-1' : 'Attr-1', 'ClusterAttr-2' : 'Attr-2'})
  ClusterID ClusterAttr-1 ClusterAttr-2
0        1a        Attr-1        Attr-2
1        1b        Attr-1        Attr-2
2        2a        Attr-1        Attr-2
3        2b        Attr-1        Attr-2
4        2c        Attr-1        Attr-2
5        2d        Attr-1        Attr-2
6        3a        Attr-1        Attr-2
```